# What's "which pyenv > /dev/null" mean?

Tags: bash, shell, pyenv

Everyone write `if which pyenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(pyenv init -)"; fi` into .bashrc etc after installation of pyenv.

I know if I didn't excute `eval "$(pyenv init -)"`, python's version would not change.

Why do I need to write `if which pyenv > /dev/null`?
What's it mean? What would happen without it?

Thanks.

Comment: This question is mistagged. As all your questions have to do with bash, the `bash` tag is missing.

Answer (score 2):

It is used to check if `pyenv` is found, but suppress the output of the `which` command.

Without it, the output of `which` would print to the console, every time `.bashrc` is sourced.